# Exceptions, unicoins, Eco mining and cupcakes

Tags: support, tags, fun, unicoins

I have just mined some Unicoins and found that, upon purchasing the reasonably priced power ups my code not longer throws exceptions, but instead spews forth a rainbow of delicious cupcakes.

There are a lot of exceptions in my code and I am very happy with the delicious, colourful cupcakes.  The cupcakes are however making me rather portly.

*Is this a plan to reduce bugs by culling developers via a delicious heart attack?*

It might be working, but only because I can no longer reach the keyboard.

Comment: Today is a very magical day.  Thank you michaelb958, and thank you unicorns.

Comment: That was a short lived glory.  **Sigh**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not sure about the cupcakes, but the unicorn mascot at the computer does look a little suspicious. Is this how all developers are supposed to become after using these unicoins?

[image]

Comment: Maybe, I just thought I was getting fat but maybe I am turning INTO a unicorn.

Comment: @BanksySan - Is your tongue hanging out and are your eyes glazing over into stars?